# Printing out sorted array

Tags: java

I have a program that reads in a .txt file, creates an array of its contents, sorts it using merge sort, and prints the sorted array out in the console. I am having trouble getting it to print out the sorted array.

```
    public static void mergesort (int[] arr, int [] temp, int p, int r)
    {
        if (p < r)
        {
            //find middle

          //sort first and second half
          mergesort(......);
          mergesort(......);
          //merge sorted halves
          merge(.................);  
        }


public static void merge (int[] arr, int[] temp, int p, int r, int q)
    {
        int i = p;
        int j = q+1;


        /*Merge back to arr[]*/
        for (int k = p; k<= r; k++)
        {
            if
             else if, etc.......
        }
    }
```

and then the driver..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] inputArray = readFile("input.txt");

   /* copy inputArray to temp array*/
  int [] temp = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);

  mergeSort ms = new mergeSort();
  ms.mergesort(inputArray, temp, inputArray[0], inputArray[inputArray.length-1]);

    for (int i: inputArray)
    {
      System.out.print(i + " \n");
    }

}
```

I've been doing a bit of research on this topic for a while and I really can't figure out how to print it out. I understand that right now it just prints out the inputArray which was created from the text file. Need something like sortedArray = merge(inputArray).

Comment: Perhaps have it return an `int[]` instead of `void` and then do exactly how you want: `sortedArray = merge(inputArray)`

Comment: That was my first thought but it gives me the "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error.

Comment: Changing the return type should have no bearing on the argument list

Comment: Are you trying to follow standard approach rather than `temp` please follow the link [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-merge-sort/)